# Gimp will not save JPG as an image

Tags: gimp

I have taken several images for an on line article. I use Gimp as a photo editor. I export the image as a JPG and half of them show up as a black screen with JPG in the center.

[image: JPG corrupted images]

All other images can be clicked on and used. If I click on the JPG marked image it says it cannot open it. Converting it back to a PNG will not work either.
What can I do to convert these images to a REAL JPG and not just a corrupted file?

Comment: Could you share one of those "corrupted" images so I may better ascertain what is happening? DropBox or Drive.

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu? Which Version of GIMP?

Comment: Gimp can export to jpg for me without problems both in 16.04 LTS and in 17.10. Please do what the two previous comments ask for. It will help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not super familiar with GIMP, so I'm not entirely sure if this will work. First, run `file jpg_file_that_doesn't_open jpg_that_opens` and compare the results. ImageMagick (`sudo apt-get install imagemagick` if not already installed) might be able to solve your issue by circumventing GIMP and converting the original .xcf files to .jpg using `convert filename.xcf filename.jpg`. However, I've read that this can be buggy and unreliable. I looked into using xcftools, but there doesn't seem to be a way to convert to JPEG, only PNG.

This shouldn't make much of a difference, but I noticed that most of the files you claim to be unable to open have a lowercase .jpg extension, while all of the ones with previews have an uppercase .JPG. You can try renaming your .jpg files to .JPG ones using `mv filename.jpg filename.JPG`.